# invalid argument error of jquery accordion in IE

Tags: jquery, accordion

The jquery accordion throws "Invalid argument." exception in IE(mine is IE8).

It works in Firefox and chrome. What may be the problem of jquery accordion with IE?

Here is the html:

```
<div id="accordion">      
   <h3><a href="#">Training</a></h3>
      <div>                
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
           <li><a href="/User/Index/4">Seminar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   <h3><a href="#">Meeting</a></h3>
      <div></div>
</div>
```

The js to call acordion:

```
 $(document).ready(
   function() {
     $("#accordion").accordion();
 });
```

The Error throws in jquery-1.3.2.min.js:

```
{J[G]=K}return J[G]},trim:function(E){return(E||"")
```

Comment: are u using the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI? seems to work fine (even in IE8) http://jsbin.com/opodi/2

Comment: I am using jquery-1.3.2.min.js, jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js and jquery-ui-1.7.custom.css. Your sample code is working fine. I have customized the css (Colors and Fonts) to the look and feel of my application, Is that may be the problem?

Comment: Upgrading the the newest version of Jquery fixed this error for me as well. I was having a problem with fadeslideshow.js causing jquery to throw this error in certain situations. Thank you @mr.moses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mr.moses said, i have updated my jquery and ui to latest and it works well now.

Answer (score 1):

invalid argument jquery-1.3.2.min.js

then in all solutions post solutions as

1. *search* `return N.toUpperCase()});` in jquery-1.3.2.min.js
2. *add* `if(K=='Infinitypx'){K=''};if(K=='NaNpx'){K=''};` after searched stmt;

actually this was a bug in jquery-1.3.2.min.js where all the scnerios were not covered.

adding this will sort out that error and it will work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different solutions, I eventually had to do something slightly different:

invalid argument jquery-1.3.2.min.js

1. Search for `return N.toUpperCase()});` in jquery-1.3.2.min.js.
2. add `if(K=='nullpx'){K=''};` after the searched string.

Other solutions seem to suggest NaN rather then null, but after debugging it that was what was coming back.

Of course if you can, just upgrade your jQuery, but that was not a option for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out all different suggestions could not figure out a solutions.

```
if(K=='Infinitypx'){K=''};if(K=='NaNpx'){K=''};
if(K=='px'){K=''};
if(K=='nullpx'){K=''};
```

The value that is getting passed for 'K' in mycase id '-38px'.

I tried addding the below code to the jquery-1.3.2 as suggested in the steps above and did not get the js error.

```
if(K=='-38px'){K=''};
```